# .htaccess and $_GET rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having an annoying issue. I have a script which uses the $_GET feature of php to get a variable from the url of the page. However, I need to know how to, first and foremost, make my page url go from

http://www.example.com/dir/dir2/page.php?value=something&anothervalue=somethingelse

to

http://www.example.com/something/dir2/somethingelse/page.php

This is confusing for me.

Now, here is the tough part: How do I $_GET the values of value and anothervalue while leaving any other url values intact at the end of page.php? Also, if a user visits http://www.example.com/something/dir2/somethingelse/page.php they will be shown the content for http://www.example.com/dir/dir2/page.php?value=something&anothervalue=somethingelse , and vice versa, right?

This is very important to the operation of my site, thanks for helping in advance! I don't know anything about .htaccess at all but I do know that it is possible to do this.

To clarify, doing this very confusing thing will actually make things much simpler in the long run as it will require much less recoding and will provide cleaner URLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*) dir/$2/$4?value=$1&anothervalue=$3 [L,QSA]
```

It will rewrite requests of `/something/dir2/somethingelse/page.php` internally to `/dir/dir2/page.php?value=something&anothervalue=somethingelse`.

But that wouldn’t prevent from requesting the latter directly but just allowing an alias.

Redirecting requests of `/dir/dir2/page.php?value=something&anothervalue=somethingelse` externally to `/something/dir2/somethingelse/page.php` is also possible with mod_rewrite but requires a little more complex rule since the URL parameters can have an arbitrary order:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)value=([^&]+)&?([^&].*)?$
RewriteCond %3&%1%4 ^([^&]+)&(([^&]*&)*)anothervalue=([^&]+)&?([^&].*)?$
RewriteRule ^dir/([^/]+)/(.*) /%1/$1/%4/$2?%2%5 [L,R=301]
```

As you see, that’s not really nice. A better solution would be to check with PHP what URL has been requested (see [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) and do the redirect with PHP (see [`header` function](http://docs.php.net/header)).

Comment: Okay, so the first one will act as a mask for the actual URL basically, and show the content as if the user had visited the real url? I can still $_GET my vars, right? If both of these are true, then I am REALLY happy! I think I wanted an internal request, that means that the page displayed is the content of /dir/dir2/page.php?value=something&anothervalue=somethingelse, even though the URL is /something/dir2/somethingelse/page.php? Will I be able to $_GET variables now from the new URL?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it is possible to do that.  Others may disagree, but I tend to think that the appropriate thing at the point you're at is to refer you to [the documentation for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  If you're going to be maintaining that complex of a set of rewrites, you're going to need to learn about it sooner or later, so it may as well be now.

Comment: Lol, glad to know it is possible.

Ill make a compromise, if I read through the documentation will you provide me with actual code? Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

For the specific rewrite you pose above, something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.php$ /dir/\2/\4.php?value=\1&anothervalue=\3 [L]
```

...although in practice I wouldn't recommend using the dot token as shown, as it will match paths with extra levels in them and screw up the rewrite. Replacing each dot with `[^/]` might work, although I would want someone who's better at regexes than I am to take a look and determine whether there are any pitfalls there as well. Anyway, the important point is that regular expressions can be very complex as well as very powerful, and a full explanation of them is way beyond the scope of this answer. Try spending some time at [http://www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for a general tutorial.

> Also, if a user visits http://www.example.com/something/dir2/somethingelse/page.php they will be shown the content for http://www.example.com/dir/dir2/page.php?value=something&anothervalue=somethingelse , and vice versa, right?

No; it only works one way. To do it both ways you would need two RewriteRules.

I'm not sure I understand your question about $_GET.  $_GET is an array that is filled with key/value pairs for each of the parameters in the URL; you may use as many or as few of them as you wish. It's not destructive--using it doesn't alter the parameters of the URL string.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, if I were to use the code: $_GET['value'] it would return something even with the rewrite?

Comment: Someone REALLY needs to make a Mod_Rewrite script in php that will do stuff like this by itself.....

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you take in http://example.com/foo and rewrite it to http://example.com/bar=foo, you get to work with the key/value pair you created, regardless of what the user sees in the browser address bar.